# Blazor non-base class inheritance

Tags: c#, inheritance, razor, blazor

Consider a simple blazor component *MyText*

```
<p>@Title</p>

public partial class MyText
{
    [Parameter] public string Title { get; set; }
}
```

In page I use it as:
`<MyText Title="Abc" />`

Now I would like to extend this component but do not want to change it, rather derive it by a new component *MyTextEx* and add another parameter. Something like:

```
@inherits MyText

<!-- Show base component something like: --!>
@base

<p>@Message</p>

public partial class MyTextEx
{
    [Parameter] public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

What I could not find how to display the base component's content? So it is rendered as:

```
<p>@Title</p>
<p>@Message</p>
```

Note this is a simplified example and my base component has a lot of parameters, events and hoping for virtual methods which could be overridden by extended/derived component. I'm trying to avoid composition like approach in razor file for base component because AFAIK I have to again populate it with parameters:

```
@inherits MyText

<MyText Title="@Title" />

<p>@Message</p>
```

I was able to find inheritance examples with base/abstract components, but could not find inheritance with *final* components.

Any idea how to achieve this?

Thanks, Csaba

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
@inherits MyText

<!-- Show base component like: --!>
@RenderBase()

<p>@Message</p>

@code 
{    
    // Message etc ...

    RenderFragment RenderBase() => builder => base.BuildRenderTree(builder);    
}
```

Comment: FWIW, I've just tried this in VS 2019 with .Net Core 3.1 on a Blazor wasm app and it wouldn't compile complaining that RenderBase does not exist in the current context, however, the solution offered by @sw1337 (below) does

Comment: Renderbase is a method declared inside @code. So you must have mistyped something.

Comment: Henk, that's because I'm dumber than a very, VERY dumb thing! :-( Sorry to have disturbed. :-)

Comment: can we manage from base this @RenderBase method?

Answer (score 3):

A more direct alternative to the accepted answer:

```
@inherits MyText

<!-- Show base component something like: --!>
@{ base.BuildRenderTree(__builder); }

<p>@Message</p>

public partial class MyTextEx
{
    [Parameter] public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Whilst I've been able to make the rendering of the base class work, I've not been able to implement the `partial class` part of your suggestion.

As written, the definition of the class just renders as text.

Comment: This "hack" works in most simple use cases but fails silently (and maddeningly) in certain scenarios where the call to base.BuildRenderTree(__builder) is wrapped in other component tags. I suspect other components might wreck the __builder reference somehow. I couldn't tell you why, but the accepted answer worked where this one didn't.

Comment: @OlaBerntsson your comment just saved me from going insane! Thank you! I would say it doesn't work because when it is wrapped in other component tags it means it is being rendered in a RenderFragment by the parent component (which is rendered later when the `__builder` builder is already finished).